# How to open a calendar in ajaxupdate panel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an ajaxpopupextender and I want to open a calendar which I want to open but I'm not getting it. Can somebody help me?

I'm using a westwind calendar. It is working fine in my rest of the project but when I try to use it in a popup window it is not coming up.

```
<ww:jQueryDatePicker ID="txtDOB" runat="server"  MaxLength="10" DisplayMode="AutoPopup" CssClass="wmDOB"></ww:jQueryDatePicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this

here in ControlID  and EventName  you have to change..

Comment: I guess u were suppose to provide me an link

Comment: <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "ddlEMRSSourceSystem" EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged" />
         </Triggers>

Comment: No friend this didnt work neither did the jquery helped me
now I m thinking to enable my text box and allow 1-12(mm)/1-31(depending on month)/year but a person cannot enter any other digit in it